# revalue numpy array by order of unique appearance count

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2D numpy array, I need to revalue the array by unique appearance count.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[6, 1, 8, 5, 3],
      [2, 7, 3, 6, 9],
      [5, 3, 2, 4, 4],
      [6, 4, 6, 4, 4]])
values, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
print('values',values)
print('counts',counts)
values [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
counts [1 2 3 5 2 4 1 1 1]

[1, 6],
[2, 4],
[3, 3],
[4, 1],
[5, 5],
[6, 2],
[7, 7],
[8, 8],
[9, 9]
```

if more than one unique have same appearance than the smallest unique come first, in this example wherever there is one it should be replace by 6, 2 should be replace by 4, 3 remain 3, 4 should be replace by 1, 5 stay 5, 6 become 2, and so on.

I have arrays of 10000*10000 and about 8000 unique so it cannot be manually and should be fast.

If it is to problematic the order of same value does not have to be from smallest to biggest must be consistent with the correct main order, meaning that 2 can transfer to 5, and 5 can transfer to 4

Comment: What is the exact output you are expecting? Does the mapping array always have the exact same elements as the uniques? Is it always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives the desired result. The stable sort makes sure the smallest value comes first in case multiple uniques have the same count.

```
values, inverse, counts = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
order = np.argsort(-counts, kind='stable')
new_values = np.empty_like(values)
new_values[order] = np.arange(1, 1+len(values))
result = new_values[inverse].reshape(arr.shape)
```

Comment: running this i get array([[1, 4, 8, 5, 3],
       [6, 7, 3, 1, 9],
       [5, 3, 6, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 2]], dtype=int64)
which doesn't give the correct answer

Comment: it seems that the inverse should also be transform somehow

Comment: @user18628648 I found my mistake and edited the answer. Should be correct now,

Comment: Why are you sorting by counts?

Comment: @MadPhysicist For me it was the easiest way to get the value mapping the OP wanted. The new values are determined by ordering the counts from high to low. Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't notice that that was the ordering.